# Although I'm ignoring namespaces when deserializing xml it does not ignore namespace of root node

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces, xml-deserialization

I'm making a XML deserializer for a certain type of XML. I already have [one question regarding it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68215415/invalidoperationexception-when-deserializing-custom-xml-lack-of-namespace) :-) Back then I was trying to conform the namespaces, I have in the sample file. But the truth is - I get XMLs from many different sources. Although they're basically the same XML, some of them follow different namespaces, or add redundant namespaces of their own. That's why **I removed namespaces from code (inside XmlRoot Attributes)** and used the following code to ignore namespaces:

```cs
private Jpk DeserializeInputFile(string path)
{
    Jpk obj;

    var fileContent = File.ReadAllText(path);
    using (TextReader textReader = new StringReader(fileContent))
    {
        using (XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(textReader))
        {
            reader.Namespaces = false;
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Jpk));
            obj = (Jpk)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }

    return obj;
}
```

Now I encountered a different situation. I received an XML file that starts with the following root:

```xml
<tns:JPK xmlns:etd="http://crd.gov.pl/xml/schematy/dziedzinowe/mf/2018/08/24/eD/DefinicjeTypy/" xmlns:tns="http://jpk.mf.gov.pl/wzor/2019/09/27/09271/">
```

When trying to deserialize it I get the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (1, 57).
> ---> System.InvalidOperationException: <tns:JPK xmlns=''> was not expected.

Previously there was no namespace in the root node. No tns:JPK, just JPK.
How can I ignore this namespace in root node?

Comment: `<tns:JPK xmlns:tns="...">` and `<JPK xmlns="...">` are the same. Namespace prefix has no meaning. No need to remove namespaces.

Comment: But if I ignore namespaces why do I get this error?

Comment: You must not ignore namespaces. You must use them. The code in your other question uses the same namespace, but without the prefix.