# Reading nested XML

Tags: c#, xml

I have a xml file and I have to store the values in the list to use it later.
The xml file contain mostly int`s and string`s and it looks like this:

```
<AllThings>
      <Anythings>
        <Anything Step="1" Name="1">
          <Somethings>
            <Something Id="10">
              <Things>
                <Thing Id="11">abc</Thing>
                <Thing Id="12">123</Thing>
              </Things>
            </Something>
            <Something Id="20">
              <Things>
                <Thing Id="21">cde</Thing>
                <Thing Id="22">345</Thing>
              </Things>
            </Something>
            <Something Id="30">
              <Things>
                <Thing Id="31">efg</Thing>
                <Thing Id="32">567</Thing>              
              </Things>
            </Something>
            <Something Id="40">
              <Things>
                <Thing Id="41">ghi</Thing>
                <Thing Id="42">789</Thing>                
              </Things>
            </Something>
    </Somethings>
    </Anything>
    <Anything Step="2" Name="2">
          <Somethings>
            <Something Id="10">
              <Things>
                <Thing Id="11">aaa</Thing>
                <Thing Id="12">111</Thing>
              </Things>
            </Something>
            <Something Id="20">
              <Things>
                <Thing Id="21">ccc</Thing>
                <Thing Id="22">333</Thing>
              </Things>
            </Something>
            <Something Id="30">
              <Things>
                <Thing Id="31">eee</Thing>
                <Thing Id="32">555</Thing>              
              </Things>
            </Something>
            <Something Id="40">
              <Things>
                <Thing Id="41">ggg</Thing>
                <Thing Id="42">777</Thing>                
              </Things>
            </Something>
        </Somethings>
        </Anything>
    </Anythings>
</AllThings>
```

What is the best way to get the values from this kind of xml and store it in the list(s)?

I've tried with `using System.Xml;` to create a reader and make `reader.ReadToFollowing("Something")` in combination with `reader.GetAttribute("Id")`, but it hasn`t gone deep enough.
In most tutorials the xml is like:

```
<Animal type="cat">
  <Name>Bob</Name>
  <Age>8</Age>
</Animal>
```

and there it works

Comment: which fields you are getting for type, name and age?

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73640395/10024425 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/68232320/10024425

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to use `XmlSerialization`.  To do this, you will need to create a nested class structure matching your xml.  There are plenty of utilities that will do this automatically (if you search for convert xml to c# class), but I always feel, it helps to know how to construct this yourself.

I always begin with the outer shell, and work my way inwards.  So I take the root element first. AllThings has just one element AnyThings, so this class is easy to create (you will need `using System.Xml.Serialization;`):

```
[XmlRoot]
public class AllThings
{

    [XmlElement]
    public Anythings Anythings { get; set; }
}
```

Next we look at Anythings.  This holds a bunch of elements Anything, so we create the next class accordingly:

```
public class Anythings
{

    [XmlElement]
    public List<Anything> Anything { get; set; }
}
```

Only one thing extra to note here: the bunch of Anything is being represented as a `List<Anything>`.

We move down again:

```
public class Anything
{

    [XmlElement]
    public Somethings Somethings { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public int Step { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

Here there is a little more of interest: as well as an XmlElement, we have two XmlAttributes.  In your case the attribute Name could easily be an `int`, given the values in your xml, but in my view an attribute called Name is crying out to be a string!

And going on down:

```
public class Somethings
{

    [XmlElement]
    public List<Something> Something { get; set; }
}

public class Something
{

    [XmlElement]
    public Things Things { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}


public class Things
{

    [XmlElement]
    public List<Thing> Thing { get; set; }
}
```

These are all constructed in the same way as previously, leaving only one more class:

```
public class Thing
{

    [XmlAttribute]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

This (at last) adds something new, a basic XmlText element which represents the value of the node.

Having set up your classes, all that remains is to call the inbuilt deserializer, like this:

```
var xml = "<AllThings><Anythings><Anything Step=\"1\" Name=\"1\"><Somethings><Something Id=\"10\"><Things><Thing Id=\"11\">abc</Thing><Thing Id=\"12\">123</Thing></Things></Something><Something Id=\"20\"><Things><Thing Id=\"21\">cde</Thing><Thing Id=\"22\">345</Thing></Things></Something><Something Id=\"30\"><Things><Thing Id=\"31\">efg</Thing><Thing Id=\"32\">567</Thing></Things></Something><Something Id=\"40\"><Things><Thing Id=\"41\">ghi</Thing><Thing Id=\"42\">789</Thing></Things></Something></Somethings></Anything><Anything Step=\"2\" Name=\"2\"><Somethings><Something Id=\"10\"><Things><Thing Id=\"11\">aaa</Thing><Thing Id=\"12\">111</Thing></Things></Something><Something Id=\"20\"><Things><Thing Id=\"21\">ccc</Thing><Thing Id=\"22\">333</Thing></Things></Something><Something Id=\"30\"><Things><Thing Id=\"31\">eee</Thing><Thing Id=\"32\">555</Thing></Things></Something><Something Id=\"40\"><Things><Thing Id=\"41\">ggg</Thing><Thing Id=\"42\">777</Thing></Things></Something></Somethings></Anything></Anythings></AllThings>";

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AllThings));
using (var reader = new StringReader(xml))
{ 
    var allThings = (AllThings)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    //do something with allThings; 
}
```

If you use the debugger to examine allThings, you will find that it is a c# object, with a structure exactly matching your xml.  This means that you can access its values with syntax such as:

```
var test = allThings.Anythings.Anything[0].Somethings.Something[0].Things.Thing[0].Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you missed iterating through recursively with

```
.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlNode>().
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code is tested and works

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication51
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AllThings));
            AllThings allthings = (AllThings)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
    public class AllThings
    {
        [XmlArray("Anythings")]
        [XmlArrayItem("Anything")]
        public List<AnyThing> anythings { get;set;}
    }
    public class AnyThing
    {
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public int Step { get;set;}
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public int Name { get; set; }

        [XmlArray("Somethings")]
        [XmlArrayItem("Something")]
        public List<Something> somethings { get; set; }
    }
    public class Something
    {
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [XmlArray("Things")]
        [XmlArrayItem("Thing")]
        public List<Thing> things { get;set;}
    }
    public class Thing
    {
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string value { get; set; }
    }
 
}
```

Comment: Your lists have two tags like Somethings and SomeThing.  When your xml doesn't have two tags for arrays use [XmlElement(tag)] instead of XmlArray and XmlArrayItem.